# Looking for HP fanfic. HG birthday. Orb from Molly. HG & HP to alternate past. Tapestry. HP's grandparents

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, time-travel, fan-fiction

I'm looking for a Harry Potter fanfic I probably read at AO3, for 6-12 months ago.  Was then a WIP.  I may be mixing together two stories...

It's Hermiones (20th?) birthday and they're celebrating.  From Molly (even though she and Ron is broken up) she gets an glass-orb that's supposed to show her her soulmate.  It's a Weasley heirloom, that belonged to a great aunt or something.  Hermione suspects Molly has spelled it to show her Ron.

While later walking with Harry, the orb activates and starts pulling Hermione into a vortex.  Harry tries to save her and is dragged with.

In an alternate past - where Harry's grandparents are alive together with Sirius' parents/grandparents - a new name appears on the Potter's (and Black's) tapestry - Harry Potter.  This cause lots of talk between the Potter and Black patriarchs.  I think it's set while/before James and Sirius goes to Hogwarts.

Harry and Hermione seeks sanctuary at Hogwarts, and Dumbledore checks the orb - finding Molly's spell, but also some unknown magic.

Harry reunites with his family.  Harry and Hermione pretends to be married.

That is what I remember from as far as I got.  Anybody recognize it and know the title/author?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, found it (asked on Reddit)...

It's "[A Step to the Right](https://archiveofourown.org/works/14949759)" by CatsAreCool (Rachel500)

> When Harry saves Hermione's life, they find themselves in a different world and in the middle of another magical war - but at least they have each other.

It's now finished, 14 chapters, and may become first in a series.
Highly recommended!

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer in 44 hours. And congrats!